# What the best delegate or get superview?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

Can anyone help me to give reason to use delegate/protocol oriented or get superview, as I know swift use protocol oriented on code but for grab parent view or controller we still can use get superview like

**Get superview example:**

```
extension UIView {

  var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

**Use delegate example:**

```
protocol SomeDelegate {
  func didClick()
}

class Child {
  var delegate: SomeDelegate?
}
```

What Pros and Cons to use delegate or get superview ?

Example for parentView:

```
class Cell {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    self.parentViewController.view.makeToast("Something !")
  }
}
```

Example for delegate:

```
class Parent: SomeDelegate {
  func didClick() {
    self.view.makeToast("Something !")
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? Cell
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
  }
}

class Cell {
  var label: UILabel
  var delegate: SomeDelegate?

  func configure() {
    label.addGestureRecognizer(UILongPressGestureRecognizer(
        target: self,
        action: #selector(copyAction(_:))
    ))
  }

  @objc private func copyAction(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let delegate = self.delegate else {
      return
    }

    delegate.didClick()
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense, because the delegate pattern and "getting the superview" are *not* the same thing. There are plenty of times where you want the `.superview` property that have nothing to do with a delegate, and there are plenty of times to use delegates that have nothing to do with superviews. Jump on over to Apple's developer site and read up on it.

Comment: @DonMag I updated the question doesnt make sense now ?

Comment: No, because they are still fundamentally different tasks. It may be that in a situation you are considering that the delegate you will use is also a/the superview. But this is not the general case.  You would typically find the superview when you need to do something with the superview regardless of what that object is. You would use a delegate when you want to use the delegate object regardless of where that object is.

Comment: @Paulw11 yup, I know both is different but sometime we facing that issue, when we need accessing or adding something on parent view,

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is preferred, not the superview. some reasons below

1. A view added in stack is not always retained in memory after its addition. especially when no strong reference maintained (this differs when view added from XIB or SB). So in this case calling superview might sometime crash with an unrecognized selector sent on some random instance.
2. One can create a view and never add to another view. ex for sake of removing you might comment just addsubview line leaving other code as is. At this time also the superview is nil.
3. Usage of custom views under uicontrols with own reusable view stack like Collectionview,TableView etc. would change superviews in runtime. so not always guaranteed to call same superview instance.